# Magento 2 Intermittent Cache Issue - Showing a JSON code Instead of Homepage

Tags: magento2, cache

We have a multi store running with Magento 2 and sometimes when we try to load the homepage it shows the JSON below instead of the home page, it only works again if we clean cache.

Strange enough is that if we try to navigate in any other page of the website it works just fine, it is just the homepage.

Any idea what may cause that?

`{"categoryProducts":"","navigation":"","navigationTop":"","breadcrumbs":"","h1":"","title":"HIDDENSITE.com","categoryData":"<div class="category-view"></div>","bottomCmsBlock":"","url":"https://www.HIDDENSITE.com/","productsCount":"0","js_init":"","isDisplayModePage":"","currentCategoryId":"0","currency":"","store":"<div class="switcher-language">\n<div class="switcher language" data-ui-id="language-switcher" id="switcher-language-website">\n <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">\n <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger" id="switcher-language-trigger-website">\n <strong class="view-en">\n <span>Canada</span>\n </strong>\n </div>\n <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown"\n data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{\n "appendTo":"#switcher-language-website > .options",\n "triggerTarget":"#switcher-language-trigger-website",\n "closeOnMouseLeave": false,\n "triggerClass":"active",\n "parentClass":"active",\n "buttons":null}}'>\n <li class="view-us switcher-option">\n <a href='https://www.HIDDENSITE.com/us/'>UNITED STATES</a>\n </li>\n </ul>\n </div>\n</div>\n\n<div class="switcher language" data-ui-id="language-switcher" id="switcher-language">\n <strong class="label switcher-label"><span>Language</span></strong>\n <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">\n <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger" id="switcher-language-trigger">\n <strong class="view-en">\n <img src="https://www.media.HIDDENSITE.com/wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/flags/en.png" />\n <span>English</span>\n </strong>\n </div>\n <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown"\n data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{\n "appendTo":"#switcher-language > .options",\n "triggerTarget":"#switcher-language-trigger",\n "closeOnMouseLeave": false,\n "triggerClass":"active",\n "parentClass":"active",\n "buttons":null}}'>\n <li class="view-pt switcher-option">\n <a href="#" data-post='{"action":"https:\/\/www.HIDDENSITE.com\/stores\/store\/redirect\/","data":{"___store":"pt","___from_store":"en","uenc":"aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubmF0aW9ucGFjay5jb20vcHQv"}}'>\n <img src="https://www.media.HIDDENSITE.com/wysiwyg/smartwave/porto/flags/pt.png" />\n Portugu\u00eas</a>\n </li>\n </ul>\n </div>\n</div>\n</div>\n","store_switcher":"","behaviour":"","cmsPageData":""}`

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it?

Comment: Hey, are you guys still getting this error? I found out that the module from amasty "shopby" has an error, do you have that module? if that is the case, I have a solution for you guys

Comment: Same problem here.
We are on Magento 2.3.3 with NGINX/varnish and redis. Steps to repoduce
- Use mobile device
- Enable Ajax in improved lay nav module
- Purge varnish cache
- Go to category page (https://www.textiel.com/bed/beddengoed/dekbedovertrekken.html)
- Click on page 2 link in pagin bar
- Products will be loaded correctly
- Refresh full page (f5 / ctrl+r)
- You will get json in return instead of html When i repeat above on desktop device, it works properly. So it's very strange. We tried to bypass the shopbyajax call, but that doesn't make a differenc. I also just waint it to cache the

Comment: @Rus0, I'm curious what your solution for Amasty_Shopby was. Can you share that for my edification?

Comment: See: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28237